# Get value automatically similar to Excel's vlookup function

Tags: 2007, lookup-column

I want to get data from another list automatically based on a column from this list. Let's say the source list shows the ID A, B, C and the related values 1, 2, 3. In my list I show in a column one of the ID's like B, then I want to show in another column automatically value 2. How can I do this? Can I do this with a filtered lookup query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculated field with formula like:

```
=IF([ID]="A","1",IF([ID]="B","2",IF([ID]="C","3","")))
```